# How to determine if object in a list implements a class using JSTL

Tags: java, jstl

In my jsp (tag) file, I need to display a list of objects in different order if the objects implement a specific class (`Orderable`).

The display portion is fine, I just can't figure out how to determine if the object implements my Orderable class.

I need help here:

```
<c:set var="isOrderable" value="${items[0] implements 'Orderable'}" />
```

So this can work:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${isOrderable}" >
        <sorter:sortByProperty items="${items}" var="items" property="ordinal"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <sorter:sortByProperty items="${items}" var="items" property="name"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be doing this in the JSP. Do it in your servlet and expose it to the JSP.

Comment: Agreed, but this is legacy code. This is a tag file used by *many* jsp's. My hands are pretty tied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list the interface that an object implements with [Class.getInterfaces()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces()).

This can be used in the JSP as this:

```
<c:set var="isComparable" value="false" />
<c:forEach  var="interface" items="${yourobject.class.interfaces}">
  <c:if test="${interface.name eq 'java.lang.Comparable'}">
      <c:set var="isComparable" value="true" />
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

However, as Sotirios Delimanolis and Robin Jonsson said, this is a very messy and should really be moved to a more appropriate layer.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer, even though I didn't use it. It is the best answer to the question asked. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Like Sotirios Delimanolis said, this is not fit for the JSP to handle. Move it down a layer.

Any way, I'm not even sure there is a possibility to check if an object implements a given interface. The only solution i can think of is to check the actual class of the object and perhaps figure it out that way.

Example

```
<c:set var="isOrderable" value="${items[0].getClass().name == 'OrderableImpl'}" />
```

(Note that this requires at least Tomcat 7 with JSP EL 2.2)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no way to do this cleanly. Since I can't do it before hand I opted to make *another* custom tag to determine if the objects inherit the class:

Added this custom tag:

```
<sorter:isOrderable items="${items}" var="isOrderable" />
```

So that this could work:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${isOrderable}" >
        <sorter:sortByProperty items="${items}" var="items" property="ordinal"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <sorter:sortByProperty items="${items}" var="items" property="name"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Here's the java tag file that actually checks:

```
public class IsOrderableTag extends TagSupport {

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = -842326085194300052L;
    private String              var;
    private Collection<?>       items;

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {

        boolean isOrderable = false;
        if (items != null && !items.isEmpty()) {
            Object firstItem = items.iterator().next();
            isOrderable = firstItem instanceof Orderable;
        }
        pageContext.setAttribute(var, isOrderable);
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }

    //... getters and setters

}
```

This seemed like overkill at first, but for me, I would have had some pretty "messy" code (per @obourgain) on the jsp, or this cleaner implementation with Java.

(I'm not marking this as the chosen answer, since the question was how to do this on the jsp with jstl--if you really had to--and this doesn't. But, perhaps it's a good alternative for someone else in the same position I was.)